# Inject interface and identify concrete class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have an interface with multiple concrete classes (around 20). Now i need to inject the interface and based on the request identify the concrete class to execute. I don't want to write if-else block to identify the concrete class. How can we achieve it?

Comment: by showing us the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You can use `@Qualifier` to inject a specific bean by bean name.

Comment: @Developer, it seems to be a design question. I have added an answer for you, check it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is quite vague in terms of details, I am tempted to think it appears to be a design question or problem. The immediate idea that pops into the head is to implement the Strategy pattern. Of course, there are many other design patterns that one could implement to reach the end goal.

According to Wikipedia:

> The strategy pattern is a behavioral design pattern that enables selecting an algorithm at runtime

A simple diagram below gives an outline of it.

[image]

You could visit the following link to read more about it and check out a working example to get a gist of the design to implement.
[Behavior Based -> Strategy Pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/behavioral/strategy-design-pattern/)